# How to create stored procedure that returns two different groups

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, procedure

In my case The user will choose the city, location, start and end date, different sizes of basket and for each size quantity (like how many baskets of this size you want).

After that hit the search button.

I want the result that will be returned to be sorted depending on the providers. for example if provider A has all these baskets available his baskets will appear first then B provider baskets who also has all of these basket. the others providers (who has some of the ordered baskets even if it's one) after. I also want providers A and  B be to be sorted by the price. The same for the rest providers after A and B.

Is it possible to make this in one stored procedure that will be called once? If yes how?
I just learned about sql procedure recently and I don't know that much about it.

Comment: Tag dbms used. (Many products have their own versions of stored procedures, not ANSI SQL compliant.)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite difficult. So providers in the area provide baskets of different sizes and you want these to match the desired baskets. There are several basket amounts you want provided.

You'd have one subquery for the wanted basket sizes and one for the available basket sizes. You outer-join the latter to the first, then aggregate by provider and order according to availability and price.

The following query should point you in the right direction. I suppose with this as a base you can write the query you need:

```
select 
  provider,
  case when sum(missing) = 0 then 
    'available for ' || sum(price) 
  else
    sum(missing) ' baskets not available'
  end as offer
from
(
  select 
    available.provider, 
    wanted.size, 
    greatest(wanted.amount - available.amount, 0) as missing,
    wanted.amount * available.price as price
  from
  (
    select 'S' as size, 2 as amount
    union all
    select 'M' as size, 5 as amount
    union all
    select 'L' as size, 16 as amount
  ) wanted
  left join 
  (
    select provider, size, amount, price
    from baskets
    where city = @city
    and location = @location
  ) available on available.size = wanted.size
) balanced
group by provider
order by sum(missing), sum(price)
```